# MySQL Stream and piping data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, puppeteer-cluster

I am using MySQL to get urls I have for a web scraper. Currently I get the data using csv-stringify as shown below:

```
conn.query('SELECT id, URL FROM company_table')
    .stream()
    .pipe(stringifier).pipe(process.stdout);
```

I see the data in the process.stdout but how can I use the data itself as I need to pass the url and id to another function for processing. I am unsure what I need to put in place of process.stdout for my needs.

The data basically looks like `38391,ysu.edu`

I have another scraper where I stream in a csv file like

```
let fname = '/Users/tom/Scrappers/companies1k.csv';
fs.createReadStream(fname).pipe(csv()).on('data',
   (row) => cluster.queue({url: `http://www.${row.domain}`}));
```

and that works fine but I just can't see how I pipe the db stream the same way to puppeteer-cluster.

Any ideas?

Comment: Write your own function that can be used with `pipe()` and insert that into the chain.

Comment: @Barmar I am not very experienced with pipe so I am still at a loss on how I can access the data in that pipe.

Comment: It presumably receives the data as the function parameter. Read the documentation.

Comment: I did read the docs at https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows and that gave me no clue how to pipe it to something I can use. I have seen similar done using csv files like fs.createReadStream('my_file').pipe(csv()).on('data', (row) => console.log(`url: row.URL`)); but I am not sure how to do the same here.